# Unexpected output in aggregate calculator

Tags: c

I wrote a small code to calculate the aggregate and percentage of a student from marks scored by him in all of his 5 subjects and the code is as follows but the output of the code is unexpected when i input the marks of the student as 100 in all 5 then the aggregate and percentage is 0.00.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*Subjects of the student are s1, s2, s3, s4 and s5
      am = aggregate marks & pm = percentage marks*/
    int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, am, pm;                  
    printf("Enter the marks in order: ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4, &s5);
    am =  s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
    pm = am/5;
    printf("Your aggregate marks are: %f", am);
    printf("Your percentage marks are: %f", pm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mismatching [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format specifiers and arguments lead to *undefined behavior*. Same with [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: I also suggest you make a habit to check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Even if that worked, it would be the average, not a percentage.

Comment: Lastly, integer arithmetic will never result in a floating point value.

Comment: @molbdnilo the marks are out of 100 so suppose if I scored 100 in all 5 then the sum will be 500 which will be divided by 5 and will give 100% so the answer will be percentage not average

Comment: @TusharSharma: Well, it's the average percentage then.

Comment: @alk yes that's what it is asked to calculate.

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, Then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.  OPs posted code results in 7 (serious) warnings.  Fix them and your problems will disappear

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work as intended because you are asking `scanf` to read 5 `float`s from input and are storing them in `int`s. Use `%d` instead of `%f` if you want the input to be treated as integers or change declaration of the variables to `float` if you want them to be floating point numbers.

Comment: Why %f is used for float type and I assigned all variables float so using %d doesn't make any sense for me because it is used for int datatype as far as I know.

Comment: You declared the variables as `int`. This means the compiler will treat them as integer numbers and thus you can't tell `scanf` to treat them as `float`s.